# Is it possible to apply antialiasing/other to better draw stretched TIcon?

Tags: c, winapi, c++builder

i am using C++ Builder 2010 and i can use windows or native api/vcl for that, but is this possible when i am drawing 16x16 icon resized to 32x32?

Comment: Use a decent icon editor and add a 32x32 image to the icon.

Answer (score 1):

There's [`LoadIconWithScaleDown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775703%28VS.85%29.aspx) but that goes in the other direction, from a large image to a smaller one. And even then 32 down to 16 is probably on the edge of what will work well.

Otherwise I think you are asking for something verging on the impossible. To get a decent 32px icon from a 16px icon isn't possible in general.

Anti-aliasing is something you do to vector graphics, but you have a raster image.

What you really need to do is get a group of icons at the appropriate sizes.